# how to get most recent mySQLdump tool

Tags: mysql, dump

Perhaps not really a suitable SO question but I'll give it a try.

When I try to dump my DB from the remote server, my MySQL workbench for MacOS tells me:

Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysqldump is version 5.7.12, but the MySQL Server to be dumped has version 5.7.15.
Because the version of mysqldump is older than the server, some features may not be backed up properly.
It is recommended you upgrade your local MySQL client programs, including mysqldump, to a version equal to or newer than that of the target server.
The path to the dump tool must then be set in Preferences -> Administrator -> Path to mysqldump Tool:

I have version 6.3 installed, and the built-in "check for updates" only tells me I already have the latest version.

Does anyone know where I can go to download this more recent dump tool? I looked around on the MySQL.com but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 10):

There's a simple way to solve your problem.

Just go on google type: mysqldump 5.7.20 (this number is the version are you looking for, in my case is 5.7.20)
choose the link site from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
on that page scroll down until you see a list of avaible downloads, choose your operating system (in my case is Windows) then... download the zip that has the version you are looking for.
unzip that folder... go to bin inside it... from there copy mysqldump and paste it into your MySQLWorkbench folder... (replacing the one is in there)
restart your MySQLWorkbench... and that is all.

Comment: The solution for Workbench 6.3, which has mysqldump 5.7.17, is to change mysqldump path to Server 5.7, which has version 5.7.22. The path should be here: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe

Comment: I tried to use the latest version: mysqldump 8.x.x.x but failed. But then I downloaded 5.7.31 and was successful in doing data export.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the mysqldump.exe.The up to date version of the exe can be found in. To solve the issue just go to Edit->Preferences->Administrator ,and browse the following path 
for example C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47\mysqldump.exe

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you have two separate installations of the SQL server, you might be pointing to the wrong sqldump.